# Children are undefined when using <Route /> from react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

FYI, I am using version 3.0.0 of react-router.

Currently, I am adding a parent route component that acts as a footer wrapped around child components. While the parent component will render correctly, I keep receiving the error `` Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `children` is undefined `` and no children components render. My routes currently look like:

```
export default(store) => {
return [
<Route
  path=""
  component={Footer}
 >
   <Route
    path="main/intro"
    component={Intro}
   />
   <Route
     path="main/payments"
     component={Payments}
    />
</Route>,
  ]
}
```

And the Footer parent component looks like

```
export function Footer({ children }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {children}
      <div className={divStyle}>
        <OpenEmail />
      </div>
      <div className={divStyle}>
        <Menu />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

It seems that any version of react-router above v4, nested  should not be used, but I cannot figure out why I am running into this error with a version below v4

Comment: Route has render method

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using propTypes to declare a type for the `children` prop on your Footer component, but since it's being rendered by the `component` prop of your Route, it is not receiving any and causing a type mismatch.  You'd either need to change the propType to be valid when no children are present, or use the `render` method as Satif suggested in the comments like so:

```
<Route
  path=""
  render={(props) => <Footer {...props}><div>I am a child</div></Footer>}
 >
   <Route
    path="main/intro"
    component={Intro}
   />
   <Route
     path="main/payments"
     component={Payments}
    />
</Route>
```

Comment: That makes sense, although what exactly goes where ```<MyKids/>``` is mentioned? I changed my props to exactly what you mentioned and children are still coming in as undefined :/

Comment: Whatever elements you want to render as children of the ```Footer``` component where you are invoking ```{children}```

Comment: Would that mean literally putting the wrapper components and everything in them into the render method? I actually have a number of other child routes, but I put just two here for simplicity. Because if I put everything into that render method, it's going to be very large.

Comment: Not necessarily, only components where you need to render children or apply specific props or some other scenario that requires it.